only first additional connected monitor is displaying
I have a laptop connected to two monitors through a DisplayPort daisy-chain, but only the first one that I turn on actually works. For example, running
xrandr --output DP-3-1-8 --right-of eDP-1 --auto --output DP-3-8 --left-of eDP-1 --auto 

only turns DP-3-1-8 on, while running
xrandr --output DP-3-8 --left-of eDP-1 --auto --output DP-3-1-8 --right-of eDP-1 --auto 

only turns DP-3-8 on. Splitting them up into separate commands means whichever one is run first works. If the first --auto is removed, only the second output turns on.
output of xrandr:
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5120 x 2640, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1200+1280+1440 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 301mm x 188mm
   1920x1200     60.03*+  60.03
   1920x1080     60.03
   1600x1200     60.03
   1680x1050     60.03
   1400x1050     60.03
   1600x900      60.03
   1280x1024     60.03
   1400x900      60.03
   1280x960      60.03
   1440x810      60.03
   1368x768      60.03
   1280x800      60.03
   1280x720      60.03
   1024x768      60.03
   960x720       60.03
   928x696       60.03
   896x672       60.03
   1024x576      60.02
   960x600       60.03
   960x540       60.03
   800x600       60.02
   840x525       60.03
   864x486       60.03
   700x525       60.03
   800x450       60.02
   640x512       60.03
   700x450       60.03
   640x480       60.02
   720x405       60.02
   684x384       60.03
   640x360       60.02
   512x384       60.02
   512x288       60.02
   480x270       60.02
   400x300       60.02
   432x243       60.02
   320x240       60.02
   360x202       60.02
   320x180       60.02
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1-8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3-8 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1080     60.00    24.00
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94
   1600x1200     60.00
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
DP-3-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3-1-8 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00
   1920x1200     59.88
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     59.95
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1200x960      59.99
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
DP-3-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

I don't get any errors, and they were working fine a few weeks ago. I've tried looking some things up but I'm not sure where else I should be searching and what words to use.
